# Why is Facebook open graph (og:video) not working for my custom video player?

Tags: facebook, flash, video, embed, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to embed my own custom video player on Facebook, and I don't know why it does not work. It was build with the YouTube API.  After much googling around, I still can't find an answer.

Below is the code I am using. What could be the problem? Any ideas?

(Note, if I use YouTube URL it works, but when I use my own working swf, it doesn't)

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="870699924261475"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="example.com"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="This is my title"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="this is a description of my own video player"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.example.com"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="video"/>
<!--<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.youtube.com/v/vIu85WQTPRc?version=3" /> -->
<meta property="og:video" content="http://www.example.com/example.swf?v=vIu85WQTPRc" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="374" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="202" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/logo_beta.gif"/>
```

Comment: did you manage to get it working? Is this the same as Custom Stories or part of the Share Dialog

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the og:secure_url property for people browsing facebook with HTTPS.